# How to divide this string into different columns, with certain criteria?

Tags: r, string

I need to separate in *different columns* the following string.

```
string = "H:Half-yearly/\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\"/\"A:Total (all instruments)\"/\"B:Foreign exchange\"/\"5J:All countries (total)\"/\"A:Total (all counterparties)\"/\"5J:All countries (total)\"/\"A:Total (all sectors)\"/\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"/\"USD:US dollar\"/\"A:Total (all maturities)\"/\"A:Total (all ratings)\"/\"3:Total (all methods)\"/\"C:Net - net\"/H:A:A:B:5J:A:5J:A:TO1:USD:A:A:3:C/19168639.500/19152273.382/16570931.333/16504473.647/17872834.161/18034192.743/18340526.000/18976252.550/20062793.085/21044051.427/24842918.967/27753186.875/28401867.500/30250361.915/32530354.232/31530866.590/38308896.039/41071533.056/47782829.500/55333816.999/61778797.231/51013377.932/49245196.366/49565196.793/53615697.500/57490500.198/64325378.832/63517357.370/66711084.080/66852981.078/71298569.378/67974223.786/71903681.455/73329825.600/69380854.616/66121018.427/75421500.092/70549837.635/77043460.796/74755778.576/84448087.669/80187033.245/87298666.811"
```

What I need to do is: *everytime there is a* `/` *create a new column*.

such for example: `hello/world/it's feb 17 2020/12345` becomes a 4 column object with all this information inside the `/`.

I've tried this following code but it doesn't work because it says: "that the object `string` is not a character", but the object `string` *is a character*.

```
string = "H:Half-yearly/\"A:Outstanding - notional amounts\"/\"A:Total (all instruments)\"/\"B:Foreign exchange\"/\"5J:All countries (total)\"/\"A:Total (all counterparties)\"/\"5J:All countries (total)\"/\"A:Total (all sectors)\"/\"TO1:Total (all currencies)\"/\"USD:US dollar\"/\"A:Total (all maturities)\"/\"A:Total (all ratings)\"/\"3:Total (all methods)\"/\"C:Net - net\"/H:A:A:B:5J:A:5J:A:TO1:USD:A:A:3:C/19168639.500/19152273.382/16570931.333/16504473.647/17872834.161/18034192.743/18340526.000/18976252.550/20062793.085/21044051.427/24842918.967/27753186.875/28401867.500/30250361.915/32530354.232/31530866.590/38308896.039/41071533.056/47782829.500/55333816.999/61778797.231/51013377.932/49245196.366/49565196.793/53615697.500/57490500.198/64325378.832/63517357.370/66711084.080/66852981.078/71298569.378/67974223.786/71903681.455/73329825.600/69380854.616/66121018.427/75421500.092/70549837.635/77043460.796/74755778.576/84448087.669/80187033.245/87298666.811"
library(tidyr)
chr2cols = separate(string, sep = "/")
str(string)
```

- How can I separate this string in more columns? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're looking to split into an array instead of columns:

```
x <- strsplit(string, "/")
```

Removing the backslash (escape character) for the `"`

```
gsub("\"", "", x[[1]])
```

Comment: Do you know how can I eliminate the "\" character inside the string? thanks

Comment: @carlo updated to remove the escape character for the quotation marks